# empty the file is not working in find

Tags: linux, find

I want to empty the file which is more than 30 MB size. I tried to solve that using `find` command.

```
   find . -maxdepth 1 -size +32M -exec cat /dev/null > {} \;
```

and

```
   find . -maxdepth 1 -size +32M -exec echo -n > '{}' \;
```

But the both commands doesn't empty the file.Instead of that ,it creates a `{}` file.

why it doesn't empty the file? and why it creates a file called `{}`?.
what is wrong with the `find` command?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Solution**

You must use `sh -c` in this case:

```
 -exec sh -c "> {}" \;
```

**Example of usage**

Preparing files:

```
$ echo hello > a1
$ cp a1 a2; cp a1 b1; cp a1 b2
$ ls -l
total 16
-rw-r--r-- 1 ic ic 6  6. Aug 14:45 a1
-rw-r--r-- 1 ic ic 6  6. Aug 14:45 a2
-rw-r--r-- 1 ic ic 6  6. Aug 14:45 b1
-rw-r--r-- 1 ic ic 6  6. Aug 14:45 b2
```

Executing the command:

```
$ find . -name 'a*' -exec sh -c '> {}' \;
```

Checking the results:

```
$ ls -l
total 8
-rw-r--r-- 1 ic ic 0  6. Aug 14:45 a1
-rw-r--r-- 1 ic ic 0  6. Aug 14:45 a2
-rw-r--r-- 1 ic ic 6  6. Aug 14:45 b1
-rw-r--r-- 1 ic ic 6  6. Aug 14:45 b2
$ cat a1
$ cat b1
hello
```

As you can see, files that are starting with `a` are now empty; and other files are not.

**Explanation**

When you make something like

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -size +32M -exec cat /dev/null > {} \;
```

you make this redirection not inside the `exec` command, but outside of it.

```
( find . -maxdepth 1 -size +32M -exec cat /dev/null )  ===> ( {} \; )
```

Of course it is incorrect. You must make this redirection inside the command that is executed by `find`. To do that, you must run a new shell inside the `exec` command. You make this using `sh -c`.